# Load Ckeditor in lazy loaded module not working

Tags: angular, ckeditor, lazy-loading

I am using Angular 7
I want to implement ckeditor in my one of component that is lazy loaded.

I am referring this link for same.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-ckeditor-p5eqjg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

When I am loading ckeditor on app.component.ts it works fine.

But When I try loading same ckeditor by creating a custom component 
and then loading it into lazy loaded component/module its not working at all.

I have created CKeditor custom component and wrote same code as

> code for app.component.ts is in ck-editor.component.ts
>       code for app.component.html is in ck-editor.component.html

I  have lazy loaded module src\app\components\portal-administration\portal-administration.module.ts

> so code for app.module.ts is in portal-administration.module.ts

so imports for ckeditor are in this file portal-administration.module.ts

```
import { CKEditorModule } from 'ng2-ckeditor';
imports: [
    PortalAdministrationRoutingModule,
    TranslateModule.forChild({
        loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useClass: TranslateLanguageLoader,
            deps: [HttpClient],
        },
        isolate: true,
    }),
    CKEditorModule
],
```

and using it in another component which follows lazy loaded routing like this

> `<app-ck-editor>loading1</app-ck-editor>`

here 'app-ck-editor' is seletcor for my custom ckeditor component .. 
Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Any error in terminal or in console?

Comment: If possible fork your code in stackblitz, then I can help you to debug the issue.

Comment: `<app-ck-editor>loading1</app-ck-editor>` Are you loading this component directly or through routing?

Comment: Did you get `'app-ck-editor' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-ck-editor' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.` this type of error in browser's console?

Comment: @ShilpiJaiswal Basically your problem is CKEditor not working on lazy loaded module ??

Comment: @Shilip refer this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kedevf?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Here is example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lazy-load-brzlhh , where ckeditor using inside a lazy loaded component.

Comment: @hrdkisback thanks a lot .. your link worked for me..https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kedevf?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html but what change I did is that.. i started using ckeditor directly in lazy loaded module .. instead of calling it from other custom component.

Comment: @Sayan Samanta,. Thanks !! your link is also beneficial.

Comment: @Sayan The stackblitz link doesn't seems to be working anymore?